# How to localize string ordering in SQLite with EF Core

Tags: sqlite, encoding, entity-framework-core, collation, collate

I’m using SQLite v3 database with EF Core.

My database contains entries with diacritics, like this:

1. Bratislava
2. Leopoldov
3. Lučenec
4. Ľuboriečka
5. Veľký Krtíš

I need to sort these entries alphabetically I.e. get them ordered as above.

The problem is that by default, SQLite sorts strings in BINARY collation, which results in the following order:

1. Bratislava
2. Leopoldov
3. Lučenec
4. Veľký Krtíš
5. Ľuboriečka

How can I ensure that database results are ordered properly?

**UPDATE**

I've found this function for adding collation to SQLite. However, I don't know how to apply the collation to a schema (using code first approach).

```c#
var connection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString);
connection.CreateCollation("SLOVAK_COLLATION", localComparer);

options.UseSqlite(connection);
```